# Conditionally load a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm setting up a table component, and I want it to have a table loading shimmer component render if the data is still loading.

Now I'm passing the data to the table component, and loading it in a custom hook from React Table package. The thing is, when the data goes there and the data hasn't been loaded I get an error. That's because the data is being looped over to render it.

So I want the data to either not be looped over yet, or have some kind of default argument.

I've tried to add a default array with an empty object in it, but then I get the same error.

I could have the component which calls the table render it conditionally, but I think it would be nice to make the table be able to do it.

My table component:

```
const Table = ({ headerTxt, columns, data, isLoading }) => {
  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable({
      columns,
      data,
    });

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Header>
        <h6>{headerTxt}</h6>
      </Header>
      {isLoading ? (
        <>Loading component goes here</>
      ) : (
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
          <thead>
            {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                  <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                    {column.render("Header")}
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row, i) => {
              prepareRow(row);
              return (
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                  {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                    return (
                      <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Does someone know how I can do this?

Comment: What's the error, and what specific value(s) are you passing it?  Does this table hook/component not support empty sets of data?  If it doesn't support an empty array (which I would interpret as a successful result set of zero records) then I'd argue it shouldn't be used...

Comment: The error is data.forEach() is not a function. It doesn't seem to support something like that.

Comment: And what is the value of `data` at that time?  That error implies that `data` is not an array.  Does the hook/component *expect* it to be an array?  If so then that sounds like the problem... you're passing something that isn't an array where an array is expected.

Comment: That's it! I was indeed passing an empty object instead of an array initially. Thanks, I fixed it now :)